# connect a server directory with an xml element in php

Tags: php, xml

i'm new in php.
I have a directory in my server called weather_icons which exists png images.
The name of every image corresponds in the xml element `<sinthikes>`.
I'm trying to create an if condition where will connect the name of the image with the value of every xml element `<sinthikes>`.  For example : if $sinthikes = 100 display the image 'weather_icons/100.png'
if $ sinthikes = 101 display the image 'weather_icons/101.png'

Here's the code

```
foreach ($item_array as $item) {
            if ( make_safe($item['description']) == $_GET["description"] ) {
            $dirname = "weather_icons/";
            $item['sinthikes'] = glob($dirname."*.gif");
            $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
                $html .= 
                '<li><div id="Left1">' .make_safe($item['title']) . '<br><br><br><p>' . make_safe($item['timestamp']) . 
                '</p></div>
                <div id = "Left2">' . make_safe($item['temp']) . '<br>' . make_safe( $item['elevation'] ) . '<br>' . make_safe($item['humidity']) . '
                </div>
                <div id="Right1">' . make_safe( $item['beaufort'] ) . '<br>'
                .  ' <img src= "' . $item['sinthikes'] . '" /><br /> ' . ' </div></li>' ;
            $html .= '</ul>';
            echo '</dd>';
            }
        }
```

the xml file

```
<item>
    <title>8ο SEK Epanomis</title>
    <description>Thesaloniki</description>
    <sinthikes>101</sinthikes>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Center</title>
    <description>Thesaloniki</description>
    <sinthikes>102</sinthikes>
</item>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right bro, but before posting here you'll have to give it a shot by yourself - downvoted until you show a real try.

Comment: i'm searching for something counterpart to what i need but i didn't find anything yet.. 1 ) http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=239 2 ) http://www.fsi-viewer.com/?show=/tutorial.html&tutorial=phpshowcase

Comment: you do not have an extension (.png or .gif whatever) and a path with your filename in `<img src="..."`

Comment: @Loic As you cas see i found a solution by myself , so it's time to uncheck the downvote , cause i can't ask more questions..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the way to display the image!
Here's is the code.Thanks anybody for helping me

```
foreach ($item_array as $item) {
        if ( make_safe($item['description']) == $_GET["description"] ) {
        $dirname = "weather_icons/";
        $item['sinthikes'] = ( $dirname . $item['sinthikes'] . ".gif" );
        $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
            $html .= 
            '<li><div id="Left1">' .make_safe($item['title']) . '<br><br><br><p>' . make_safe($item['timestamp']) . 
            '</p></div>
            <div id = "Left2">' . make_safe($item['temp']) . '<br>' . make_safe( $item['elevation'] ) . '<br>' . make_safe($item['humidity']) . '
            </div>
            <div id="Right1">' . make_safe( $item['beaufort'] ) . '<br>'
            .  ' <img src= "' . $item['sinthikes'] . '" /><br /> '
             . '
            </div></li>' ;
        $html .= '</ul>';
        echo '</dd>';
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for `if ...`, because the required filename is already part of your `<item>`.

All you need to do is bringing together...

(1) the HTML for displaying an image:

```
<img src="/path/filename.png" />
```

(2) the syntax to read that value from your XML, which seems to be:

```
$item['sinthikes']
```

(3) for this result:

```
$img = "<img src=\"weather_icons/" . $item['sinthikes'] . ".png\" />";
```

Comment: michi thanks for your time again.i have just edit my code i have done something similar to what you send me but i have a problem with the icon. i can't display it for some reason.

Comment: @marYOs what response do you get instead of an icon? I imagine that the path to the icon isn't correct. Try to write static HTML (without PHP) to display an icon. When you succeed, adapt your PHP.

Comment: no michi ,  the path is right.  i insert this line outside the $html varriable : foreach( $images as $item['sinthikes'] )  and the 4th line will become : $images = glob($dirname."*.gif");  this code displays all the icons , but i don't need them all ...